# If $f(x+1)=f(x)$ then?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, periodic-functions

Let $f: \ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x+1) = f(x)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then which of the following statement(s) is/are true?

1. $f$ is bounded.
2. $f$ is bounded if it is continuous.
3. $f$ is differentiable if it is continuous
4. $f$ is uniformly continuous if it is continuous

I took the example of

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\tan(\pi x) & x \neq \displaystyle \frac{n}{2}\\
1 & x = \displaystyle \frac{n}{2}
\end{cases}$$

$n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This function satisfies the given condition and $f(x)$ is unbounded, so we can exclude the first option.

Now since the example we took is not continuous at $x = \frac{n}{2}$, I think if $f$ satisfies the given condition and is continuous then it is bounded. Is there any theorem which states: if $f$ is periodic and continuous then it is bounded? If yes, how to prove it?

I think we can even discard the third option by defining a triangle function

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x & 0 \leq x \leq \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\\
f(x)=1-x & \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1
\end{cases}$$

$$ f(x+k) = f(x), \ k \in \mathbb{Z} $$

now this function is continuous all over $\mathbb{R}$ but not differentiable at $x = \frac{n}{2}$.

The only left option is the 4th one. I know the basics of uniform continuity but not how to solve in this case. If $f$ is periodic and continuous, does this imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous? How to prove this if it is true?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I took examples like f(x) = tan(pi*x)[that is periodic with period 1 and unbounded,so i think 1 option can be discarded]

Comment: @NileshKhatri That's a good example to exclude option 1, except for a minor detail: It's not defined for $x = 0.5$. Easily fixable (you just define it to have your favourite value at that point), but it must be addressed. What about the others?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For problem 2), do you know anything about a maximum/minimum of a continuous function on a finite, closed interval, like $[0,1]$? Can you use that and apply the periodicity premise to get a final answer for problem 2?

Comment: See also: [How do I show that all continuous periodic functions are bounded and uniform continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775045).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 2 and 4 essentially boil down to the following fact:
Consider 
$$
f|_{[0,1]}
$$
that is $f$ restricted to the interval $[0,1]$. This interval is closed and bounded, hence compact.
You have that continuous functions on compact intervals are bounded and uniformly continuous. Can you conclude using the fact, that $f$ is periodic with period $1$?

Comment: Does this theorem- continuous functions on compact intervals are bounded and uniformly continuous , is valid in complex plane too?

Comment: Yes, continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous, even in the complex plane. In fact, it even holds for any compact metric space; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-mapping-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous for a more detailed answer.