# $f(x)=(\sin(x))^2$is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

Q:

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=(\sin(x))^2$,prove $f(x)$is uniformly continuous.


I tried to go by definition:$|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

I transformed as followed

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|(\sin(x))^2-(\sin(y))^2|=|\sin(x)+\sin(y)||\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq1\cdots?$

I don't find how do I transform the equation.(When and How do I connect $\epsilon$ and $\delta\cdots$ ?)

Comment: You might find it nicer to write $(\sin(x))^2$ in terms of $\cos(2x)$. If you have access to the mean value theorem, then I would use it!

Comment: I would rather use periodicity and Heine theorem.

Comment: $ \lvert \sin x+\sin y\rvert\lvert \sin x-\sin y\rvert<\epsilon $ is implied by $ 2\lvert \sin x-\sin y\rvert<\epsilon $ is implied by $ \lvert \sin x-\sin y\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{2} $. Use the uniform continuity of sine function to conclude the rest.

Comment: A more general result https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775045/how-do-i-show-that-all-continuous-periodic-functions-are-bounded-and-uniform-con

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just write till your last step...$|f(x)-f(y)|=|(\sin(x))^2-(\sin(y))^2|=|\sin(x)+\sin(y)||\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq 2|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|$

Now $\sin(x)$ is a differentiable function.....hence you can write
$\sin(x)-\sin(y)\leq (x-y)\cos(\theta)\leq x-y$ where $x\leq\theta\leq y$ or $y\leq\theta\leq x$ depending on if $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$
So $|f(x)-f(y)|=|(\sin(x))^2-(\sin(y))^2|=|\sin(x)+\sin(y)||\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq 2|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq 2|x-y|$. Now if for chosen $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ you have your required condition.
What I used here is the Lipschitz criteria. Every continuously differentiable function satisfies lipschitz and hence is uniformly continuous

Comment: Please, write `\sin(x)` to display $\sin(x)$ i.e. add a backslash.

Comment: It's worth learning a few more MathJax tips. For big, complicated, or important equations, try using `$$` instead of `$` to enclose your code. This renders your maths in display mode, e.g. `$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x).$$` renders like so:$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x).$$I would also suggest having a look at [this entry](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5024#5024) in the MathJax tutorial, for a much nicer way to render the really long equations (such as your first one).

Comment: I know mathjax and have been using it since 2018. I'll edit it . I wrote it from my mobile phone and I just copied the code from the op.

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee Oops! I believe you. I didn't just make the assumption out of thin air; I checked most of your other answers and didn't find any display maths. But, I should have seen that you just copied the OP.

Comment: @TheoBendit I am mostly used to latex. And I use \displaystyle to format it in the same line . Otherwise I do not much like to bring an expression on the next line as I add a lot of parentheses to provide reasons or questions for a particular step. It has become a habit.... and I actually write anything as I would write in pen and paper. And being a little miserly in nature...I actually try to use as less space on the paper as possible and so I start writing every line from the left edge.lol.

Answer (score 5):

$|f'(x)|=|2\sin x \cos x| \leq 2$. By MVT $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 2|x-y|$.

Alternatively, $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\sin x+\sin  y||\sin x-\sin  y|\leq (1+1)|\sin x-\sin  y|$ and $|\sin x -\sin y|=|\int_x^{y} \cos t dt| \leq |\int_x^{y} 1 dt|=|x-y|$.

Answer (score 1):

A more general result:

> The product of bounded and uniformly continuous functions is again bounded and uniformly continuous.

**Proof:** Exercise. $\square$

Using this result, take $f=g=\sin:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

To slightly mirror the proof of the general result, if we know a priori that $\sin:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and bounded by $1$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|<\varepsilon/2$.

Now, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have
$$\begin{align}
|\sin(x)^2-\sin^2(y)|
&=|\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)\sin(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)-\sin^2(y)|\tag{1}\\
&\leq|\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)\sin(y)|+|\sin(x)\sin(y)-\sin^2(y)|\tag{2}\\
&=|\sin(x)||\sin(x)-\sin(y)|+|\sin(y)||\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\tag{3}\\
&\leq 2|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\tag{4}\\&<2\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon
\end{align}$$
where we used the triangle inequality between lines $(1)$ and $(2)$ and the fact that $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ between lines $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the following theorem, then the proof is trivial:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

Since $\sin^2$ is the product of two differentiable functions, it is differentiable, and so it is continuous. In particular, $\sin^2$ is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$. Hence, it is uniformly continuous on $[0,2\pi$]. By periodicity of $\sin^2$, it is therefore uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$.