# $f$ is continuous, no constant and periodic $\implies$ f is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, periodic-functions

> $f:\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous, no constant and periodic $\implies$f is bounded.

**My answer:**

Suppose $f$ is unbounded, we have many possibilities, but since $f$ is continuous so it is unbounded

$$ \text{Does not exist} \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)
\text{ or} \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty
$$

If the limits do not exist how do I?

Suppose that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty$ the remaining cases are treated in an analogous way.

Now
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty \iff \forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists \delta>0: x>\delta \implies f(x)>\epsilon$.
As $f$ is periodic, let us suppose of period $P$, for $a\in\mathbb R$, $f(a)=f(a+P)=...=f(a+nP), n\in\mathbb N$.

For $\epsilon=2f(a)>0$,
$\exists \delta>0, \forall x>\delta \implies f(x)>2f(a)$ but this is a contradiction (isn't it?), because in $]\delta,+\infty[$ has of existing natural $m$ such that $a+mP>\delta$ because $\mathbb N$ is not increased (is it correct?), and in this case, $f(a+mP)=f(a)<2f(a)$.
What do you think ?

Comment: It is bad form to use both "If" and "$\implies$". The symbol takes precedent over the word, so what you have is a premise that has a premise but no conclusion; that is, "(if $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and periodic)" is your incomplete premise. Use either "If...then", or just $\implies$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it was "just" a little rook. Thanks

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In my book it's not so much bad form as simply incoherent: "If A implies B then..." is not what was meant

Comment: Hint: if $f$ is continuous and period (say with period $1$), then any value it attains, it will attain on $[0,1]$. What do we know about continuous functions on closed and bounded intervals?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I agree; I was trying to be kind...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show that all continuous periodic functions are bounded and uniform continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775045/how-do-i-show-that-all-continuous-periodic-functions-are-bounded-and-uniform-con)

Comment: I just wanted to know if my resolution is correct or not, if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a bounded set. Now observe that by periodicity, there is a compact interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(\mathbb{R}) = f([a,b])$. What do we know about the image of compact sets under continuous functions?

Comment: Are limited. What I wanted to do in my answer was not to use compactness, just initial calculus, so to speak

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: I just wanted to know if my resolution is correct or not, if possible